# Issue with setting chart data in VB

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with my Macro in which I am attempting to have a chart display an active range. To begin with, I have a repeated IF statement which basically decides which cells will be selected dependant on the value of a cell (Set ab = Cells(57,19)). See example below…

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets(“Parameters”)
wb.Activate
ws.Select
Dim ab As Range
Set ab = Cells(57, 19)
Dim rng As Range

If ((ab < 2) And (ab >= 1)) Then
Range(“g77:j90”).Select
End If

If ((ab < 3) And (ab >= 2)) Then
Range(“g77:j95”).Select
End If

If ((ab < 4) And (ab >= 3)) Then
Range(“g77:j100”).Select
End If
```

Following this I want “chart 6” to display this selection as the source data.

```
Dim CHARTDATA As Range

Set CHARTDATA = selection


Chart6.SetSourceData Source:=CHARTDATA, PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

However, I recieve the error message “run-time error “424”: object required”. I believe this is due to the selected range being deselected once chart 6 is being altered? To fix this I tried storing the range selection to CHARTDATA, but obviously this hasn’t worked neither.

How can I set the data selected via the IF statement to display in chart 6?

Any and all ideas are welcome, and apologies if this is a repeated and very basic question (I’m totally new to VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim aB As Double
Dim CHARTDATA As Range
Dim Ch as Chart

Set wB = ActiveWorkbook
Set wS = wB.Sheets("Parameters")

With wS
    aB = .Cells(57, 19).value

    If ((aB < 2) And (aB >= 1)) Then Set CHARTDATA = .Range("g77:j90")
    If ((aB < 3) And (aB >= 2)) Then Set CHARTDATA = .Range("g77:j95")
    If ((aB < 4) And (aB >= 3)) Then Set CHARTDATA = .Range("g77:j100")
End With 'wS

If Not CHARTDATA Is Nothing Then
    Set Ch = wS.ChartOjbects("Chart 6").Chart
    Ch.SetSourceData Source:=CHARTDATA, PlotBy:=xlColumns
Else
    MsgBox "CHARTDATA is not defined, your tests on aB are not met.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is substantially cleaner and easier to understand. However, I'm getting "run-time error 9 subscript out of range" now, any idea why?

Comment: @collydug : On which line? if it's on `Set wS = wB.Sheets("Parameters")`, make sure that you have a sheet called *Parameters* in the *ActiveWorkbook*. If it's on `wB.Charts.Item("Chart 6")....`, make sure that you have a chart called *Chart 6*

Comment: It's on     wB.Charts.Item("Chart 6"). When I hover my mouse over CHARTDATA on this line it displays "CHARTDATA=nothing". This spreadsheet was originally made in French and under my Microsoft Excel Objects it lists the sheets as "Feuil1 (parameters) etc..." could this be part of the problem? ]

Comment: @collydug : I'm pretty sure that the initial language won't be an issue. Do you have a chart named `Chart 6` in your workbook? I've added a test to let you know if the tests on the cell weren't met and therefore CHARDATA would be empty.

Comment: That test is returning the message box, so CHARTDATA must be empty which I can't work out why. Does the source data need to be set to a series on the Chart? Yes I definitely have Chart 6 on worksheet Parameters.

Comment: @collydug : What is the value of `aB`??

Comment: Ahhh silly mistake on my part. I'm still getting the subscript out of range though. Chances are, that's down to my incompetence also.

Comment: @collydug : I've added a variable to check if the error is coming from `Chart 6` or not, let me know which line throw the error

Comment: It's    Set Ch = wB.Charts.Item("Chart 6")     which throws it. If i record a macro and select Chart 6 it computes it and records: **activesheet.chartobjects("Chart 6").activate**

Comment: @collydug : I've edited the code to reflect that! ;)

Comment: That gets me past that line but now the Ch.SetSourceData Source:=CHARTDATA, PlotBy:=xlColumns is throwing up "Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method". Thanks so much for your help so far by the way.

Comment: @collydug : Try the edit! ;) It was because `SetSourceData` is method of `Chart` and not `ChartObject`!

Comment: It's alive :0 Thank you so much. I'm going to post another question regarding this in a minute but this is totally resolved now. Thank you.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change this so that CHARTDATA is assigned to a series rather than the the whole chart itself?

Comment: @collydug : Not super easy, you'd have to go a bit deeper with something like `Ch.SeriesCollection.Item(1).Values = CHARTDATA.Value` and `Ch.SeriesCollection.Item(1).XValues = AbscissaRange.Value`. Knowing that you'd have to know the index of the serie (here `1`) to work on the good one. Or you can add one and work with it. Give it a try and post another question if you don't manage to make it work! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Select Case` with "cheating" a little, by using the `WorksheetFunction.Roundup`.

Using `Select Case` will allow you to add more scenarios in the future easily.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChartRange()

Dim wB As Workbook
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim aB As Long
Dim CHARTDATA As Range

Set wB = ActiveWorkbook
Set wS = wB.Worksheets("Parameters")

With wS
    aB = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(.Cells(57, 19).Value, 0) ' use the round down to round down to the nearest integer
    Select Case aB
        Case 1 ' (from 1 to 1.99999)
            Set CHARTDATA = .Range("G77:G90")

        Case 2 ' (from 2 to 2.99999)
            Set CHARTDATA = .Range("G77:G95")

        Case 3 ' (from 3 to 3.99999)
            Set CHARTDATA = .Range("G77:G100")

    End Select
End With

wB.Charts.Item("Chart 6").SetSourceData Source:=CHARTDATA, PlotBy:=xlColumns

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very good as I may have to include a second data series later. Thank you very much.